# Finding the normalization of $K[X,Y]/(Y^5-X^7-XY^5)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I understand that for "relatively simple" cases, we can compute the normalization of a coordinate ring, such as $K[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3)$, quite easily (consider $Y/X$).

> However, how would one approach this in more difficult cases, such as $K[X,Y]/(Y^5-X^7-XY^5)$, where parametrizing the curve also becomes a lot more difficult. In general, is there some sort of algorithm to systematically determine the integral closure?

I am not very experienced with this, but would Puiseux series be of any use in this?

EDIT: I have changed the original question which was about "Finding the normalization of $K[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^7-XY)$", where just considering $Y/X$ would work. (I'm new here, so I'm not sure if I should have asked a new question instead.)

Comment: Consider $Y/X$ :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you elaborate on that? Would it be correct to say that because $Y/X$ has to be included (since $(Y/X)^2-X^5-Y/X$ is a monic polynomial in $Y/X$), the integral closure (normalization) has to be isomorphic to $K[Y/X]$?

Comment: Your equation shows that $Y/X$ is integral over your coordinate ring, hence we have to add it. To show that this is sufficient to get the integral closure, note that adding $Y/X$ obviously makes $(X,Y)$ into a principal ideal, hence the local ring at the origin is a DVR after adding $Y/X$. We only have to check the origin, since this was the only singularity to start with. Hence adding $Y/X$ indeed gives us the integral closure.

Comment: The integral closure is not isomorphic to $K[\frac{Y}{X}]$, it is isomorphic to $K[X,T]/(T^2-T-X^5)$, which of course also can be seen to be regular/normal by the Jacobian criterion. But note that my explaination above already shows that it is regular/normal.

Comment: You can blow up at a singular point repeatedly until the result is a nonsingular curve. This process is completely algorithmic and provably terminates. However, it will give you multiple charts, when one chart should suffice. It might possibly or even easy to recover what you want (the integral closure of the ring), but I haven't thought about it